# How to disallow interaction on a view behind uipopovercontroller

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, ios7, xamarin

I have a `UIPopoverController` that I am using and I have two buttons each displays a popup when clicked. However, I do not want the popup to be displayed at the same time - meaning I do not want the user to be able to press the one button and while the popup is displayed be able to press the other button. It seems like I have tried everything - disabling the user interaction on the buttons, hiding the view behind the pop up, using passthrough views for the pop and more. None of it works! The disabling of the user interaction seems to work for the most part but then stops disallowing the user to interact with the button and causes the application to crash...

```
popupView.PassthroughViews = new UIView[]{this.View.Superview, this.View, this.Gray}; //gray is another view that sits under the view that calls the popup
this.View.UserInteractionEnabled = false;
this.PositiveMeterBtn.UserInteractionEnabled = false; 
this.View.Hidden = true;
```

My `UIPopoverController` is declared at the class level and I have even done code like this:

```
if(popupView != null)
    return;
```

I still get multiple popups. I am using mono touch/xamarin - is this a bug with xamarin or an ios issue? Am I handling this in the correct manner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either make the popover modal but if it doesn't contain content that is meant to be modal, you shouldn't block the user.

Usually the better option is to make two helper methods and place them for instance in your app delegate. The methods take care that an existing popover is dismissed if another one is to be shown. This way you will have a maximum of on `UIPopoverController` and don't have to worry about dismissal.

```
/// <summary>
/// Shows a popover.
/// </summary>
/// <param name='controllerToShow'>the controller to show in the popover</param>
/// <param name='showFromRect'>the rectangle to present the popover from. Not used if showFromItem is specified.</param>
/// <param name='showInView'>the view the popover is hosted in</param>
/// <param name='showFromItem'>the bar button item the popover gets presented from.</param>
/// <param name='popoverContentSize'>the content size of the popover</param>
/// <param name='animated'>If set to <c>true</c>, animated the popover</param>
/// <param name='arrowDirection'>the allowed arrow directions</param>
/// <param name='onDismiss'>callback if the popover gets dismissed. Careful that the object that owns the callback doesn't outlive the popover controller to prevent uncollectable memory.</param>
public static void ShowPopover(UIViewController controllerToShow, RectangleF showFromRect, UIView showInView, UIBarButtonItem showFromItem, SizeF popoverContentSize, bool animated = true, UIPopoverArrowDirection arrowDirection = UIPopoverArrowDirection.Any, EventHandler onDismiss = null)
{
    if(AppDelegateBase.popoverController != null)
    {
        AppDelegateBase.DismissPopover(false);
    }

    if(showFromItem == null && showFromRect.IsEmpty)
    {
        // Nothing to attach the popover to.
        return;
    }

    popoverController = new UIPopoverController(controllerToShow);
    if(!popoverContentSize.IsEmpty)
    {
        popoverController.SetPopoverContentSize(popoverContentSize, false);
    }

    if(onDismiss != null)
    {
        popoverController.DidDismiss += onDismiss;
    }

    // Send a notification that a popover will be presented.
    NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.PostNotificationName("WillPresentPopover", popoverController);

    if(showFromItem != null)
    {
        popoverController.PresentFromBarButtonItem(showFromItem, arrowDirection, animated);
    }
    else 
    {
        popoverController.PresentFromRect(showFromRect, showInView, arrowDirection, animated );
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Dismisses the popover presented using ShowPopover().
/// </summary>
/// <param name='animated'>If set to <c>true</c>, animates the dismissal</param>
public static void DismissPopover(bool animated = false)
{
    if(popoverController != null)
    {
        popoverController.Dismiss(animated);
    }
    AppDelegateBase.popoverController = null;
}
private static UIPopoverController popoverController;
```

Answer (score 2):

I haven't worked with Xamarin before, but what's worked for me in native Objective-C is

```
[controller setModalInPopover:YES];
```

where `controller` is the view controller displayed within the popover.

From the UIViewController class reference:

@property(nonatomic, readwrite, getter=isModalInPopover) BOOL modalInPopover

The default value of this property is NO. Setting it to YES causes an owning popover controller to disallow interactions outside this view controller while it is displayed.

Comment: dont see this as an option with Xamarin

Comment: From what I can tell on the Xamarin forums, the line of code would look something like `myController.ModalInPopover = true;`

Answer (score 0):

One thing you might try is using the method

```
-(BOOL)shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier sender:(id)sender
```

And in that method check if one of your popover view controller's is on screen.

```
if (popupView.view.window) {
    return NO;
} else {
    return YES;
}
```